# Regular expression .*(\d+x\d+)$ must be greedy

Tags: python, regex

https://regex101.com/r/BjO6H1/1/

Regular expression: `.*(\d+x\d+)$`

Test string: android-chrome-192x192

Could you tell me why I get 2x192 as Group 1? I expected 192x192. And how to get the expected result?

Comment: Change to: `.*?(\d+x\d+)$`.

Comment: Thank you. Working. If you organize this as an answe, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You should consider to look for a non digit character before the group instead of relying on greediness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*` is greedy, you should change to:

```
.*?(\d+x\d+)$
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) for more explanation:

> When repeating a regular expression, as in `a*`, the resulting action is to consume as much of the pattern as possible. This fact often bites you when you’re trying to match a pair of balanced delimiters, such as the angle brackets surrounding an HTML tag. The naive pattern for matching a single HTML tag doesn’t work because of the greedy nature of `.*`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `?` to make the `.*` lazy:

```
.*?(\d+x\d+)$
```